# "Will you work this evening?" vs "Will you be working this evening?"

Tags: grammar, future-continuous, future-constructions

Let's suppose I'm gonna ask my collegue whether he or she is working this evening. Could you please explain what is the difference between the two phrases below?

> Will you work this evening?

> Will you be working this evening?

Which one should I use?

Comment: Personally, I'd say: Are you working tonight?

Comment: "Will you work this evening?" sounds like a request to do so.

Comment: To ***this*** native speaker, "Will you work this evening?" more strongly implies that *the addressee has a choice* (or ***had*** a choice, if the decision has already been made), whereas "Will you be working this evening?" is more likely if *someone else* (management?) has already made that decision. But perhaps I'm effectively making the same distinction as @Kate above.

Comment: To me, the first form is an invitation or request (="Are you prepared to work this evening?"), the second is a question (="Are you intending to work this evening?"). Applies equally to other verbs: "Will you take the dog for a walk?" vs "Will you be taking the dog for a walk"?

Comment: I would expect "Will you work this evening" to hear from say, my boss, when working out who is taking the evening shift.  "Will you be working this evening" I would expect to hear from a friend who either wants to know whether I'll be free this evening, or someone who would like to see me, this evening, in my place of work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When asking about arrangements we usually use the present continuous:

> 1. Are you working tonight?

When asking people to make a decision about something in the future we use *will*:

> 2. Will you work tonight?

Example (2) makes it sound as if the listener has a choice over whether they will work. It might be understood as a request by the speaker asking them to work. It depends on the context.

When asking about how someone is going to be spending their time, or when asking what activity someone will be doing at a particular point, we use *will be doing*. i.e. the future continuous:

> 3. Will you be working this evening?

Example (3) is asking whether the OP is going to be spending their time working this evening.

Given the wording of the Original Poster's question, it seems that the most suitable form for their particular query would be (1). Notice that this is the form that the Original Poster actually used in their question:

> Let's suppose I'm gonna ask my colleague **whether he or she is working this evening** ...

Comment: A variation on 1/3 is "Are you going to be working tonight?", and is how I would usually ask the question

Answer (score 5):

You should use the second option ("be working").

**Will you work tonight?** sounds rather rude, because it sounds like you are asking if they are planning on actually doing their job—as if you expect them to be *at* work, but not doing what they should be doing.

**Will you be working tonight?** is more polite, because it is simply asking if they will be *at work*.

Other questions that mean the same thing are:
**Will you be at work tonight?**
**Do you work tonight?**
**Are you scheduled to work tonight?**

Comment: Thank you! Maybe the verb "to work" has some special influence. Does your answer also apply to the phrases "Will you watch the movie tonight?" vs "Will you be watching the movie tonight?"

Comment: "Will you watch the movie tonight?" would not be interpreted as a request to do so (although "Will you watch the movie _with me_ tonight?" or "Will you watch the movie tonight _and tell me whether you find the plot as confusing as I did_?" are requests).

Comment: "Do you work tonight" is not generally ok.

Comment: @Araucaria - why not? I use that sentence all the time.

Comment: Yes, I would also say that in American english, "do you work tonight" is generally a bit awkward. I have heard it used (to mean "do you have work tonight?"), but it feels less idiomatic to me.

Comment: @randomhead Well, usually the present simple is used for actions or situations that occur regularly, or are always true: *Do you smoke / Do you eat meat? / Do you work here? / Do you work? / What do you do?* (Answer: I'm a student). But the OP's question is just about tonight, not all the time. (PS, Not my downvote!)

Comment: @Alex I am a native AmE speaker (Midwest, then East Coast) and think nothing of asking "Do you work tonight/tomorrow/this Saturday?" It seems perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @Araucaria this is all true, and yet I would consider it very common and well-understood to ask "Do you work tonight?" referring to this singular and specific night.

Comment: @randomhead I suspected there might be a dialectal difference there (main reason I put the 'generally' in there). Interesting! I'm pretty certain that's dispreferred for a majority of regions/speakers. (FWIW, I'm, a British English speaking teacher).

Comment: 100% in support of "Do you work tonight?". Also: "Are you on [tonight|this weekend]?", is common. As in "are you on duty?" or "are you on call?". Maybe it's a Midwest thing.

Answer (score 2):

Will you work this evening?

This could be a request. I want you to work this evening so I want to know if you are willing.

It could also be a question about whether you will do even a little bit of work. If you plan to work, even for 5 minutes, then I need to make sure the office has electricity. Otherwise I can rewire the office tonight.

Will you be working this evening.

This is a question I would ask if I want to know if a person will be spending a lot of time working this evening, and therefor won't be doing much else. "Do you want to go see a movie, or will you be working this evening." "I know you have a lot more to do on your project; will you be working this evening?"